# Where is PSVM in a struts MVC-2 web application?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, struts, program-entry-point

Where is public static void main() in a web application using struts framework and MVC architecture?

Comment: Are you looking for that exact method, or the main entry point for _your_ code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one, nor is there a need for one.

Web apps are not command-line apps. The "entry point" in web apps is determined by URL mapping patterns. The app server *itself* has an entry point, but how the *web app* artifacts are accessed is determined by the app server, for example, by following the servlet spec.

In the servlet spec, the entry points into *URL*-based entry points are things like `doGet` and `doPost`. In Struts 2 the default action handler entry point is the `execute` method.

Answer (score 0):

In web applications you do not main as you entry point, rather you have servlet defined in web.xml along with the url pattern associated with them and accessing through browser.